# FB.ui share dialog: “The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain”

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to implement the share dialog with the Facebook javascript sdk. When I open the dialog I get an error that the domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain.

I tried to add all domains and all sub-domains in my Facebook developers console, in the "Facebook login - valid OAuth" but maybe since I try to use the share dialog these domains should be added elsewhere?

Note: My app implement a Facebook login and I could confirm that I don't face any problems with this flow, the domains are correct for the login and the login works fine.

My code:

```
FB.ui({
   app_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
   method: 'share',
   href: 'https://something.com'
}, (response: any) => {
   console.log(response);
   });
```

[image: The error popup]

**UPDATE**

In english, the error msg I face

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match
>   the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of
>   one of the App's domains.

Funny things, in my Facebook developer console I've got 6 different URLs allowed as OAuth redirect. I tried to specify all of them as `redirect_uri` parameter and the share worked for two of them but failed for the other four ?!!??!

OAuth allowed URL (in this order) > Result of share

```
 https://mymaindomain.com/ > Share ok
 https://mymaindomain.com/something/ > Share ok
 https://mystaging.com/ > Share KO
 https://mystaging.com/something/ > Share KO
 https://m.mystaging.com/ > Share KO
 https://m.mymaindomain.com/ > Share KO
```

Comment: General facebook gives permission for email and the user profile. I think you need to take permission from Facebook and request a review of your app to enable that functionality.  Please see, approved Items in `app review` on Facebook application dashboard.

Comment: @kvk30 well thx but don't think this has something to do with permissions. Don't know any permissions related to "allow sharing" and furthermore, I use the same Facebook app ID for my app where both native iOS and Android share features are ok

Comment: Can you give me URL where you are trying to share?

Comment: @kvk30 unfortunately nothing to do with the URL to share too, tried with google.com didn't work neither :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the 'send' option instead of 'share' wich seems to be more reliable

```
 FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'https://something.com',
      app_id: XXXXXXXXXXX'
 }, (response: any) => {
      console.log(response);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but I fix it.

My solution:

1. Open Facebook APP.
2. Setting -> Basic
3. Set App Domains [something.com]
4. Set Website -> Site Url -> [https://something.com]

Comment: This is the correct answer. It works for me, you cannot add localhost but it works for your staging and production environments.